# Detecting expired sessions

Tags: php, session

So I have limited the TTL of sessions in my application. After that time of inactivity, the user can no longer do anything without being automatically redirected to the login page when making a request to a page where the user is required to be logged in.

But this isn't that user friendly really. Users will just be forwarded to the login page without any prior notice or explanation of why it occurred.

I want to notify my users by a message on the login page, that their request have been ended due to inactivity and that they need to login again. So what would be an appropriate way to solve this?

Comment: You could simply redirect them to the login page followed by a get parametre, like "login.php?why=1" and then make it write your message depending on the why state. If this is what your asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP auto-cleans expired sessions are part of the "before your code actually runs" startup, based on [probability settings/intervals](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-divisor) specified in the .ini file. This runs automatically and outside of your purview. If you need to control (or keep track of) expired sessions, then you have to disable the PHP garbage collector and roll your own. It'll be responsible for periodically scanning your session storage medium (files, database, ouija board, etc...) for expired sessions and removing them.

A better option would be to simply have long-lived session files, and log the time-of-last-access in the session somehow. Either a "it's been >XXX minutes since you last did something, please verify you're you" or "it's been XXX minute since you logged in", etc...

This keeps you from having to roll your own session expiry handler, and still leaves users "logged in", and just having to verify their status.